# Change on.('click') to hover on window resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've witten a bit of code (with the help of members on this site!) that converts a nav menu (ul) to and from a mobile version when the browser window is resized.

I have one problem – I'm using `$('#access').on('click', 'li.dd a', function() {` to show the sub-menus on small screens and I'd like to convert that to on hover/mouseover/out for larger screens.

This is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/54zpt/6/

Any help would be much appreciated!!

**Update:**

Am I over complicating this..? Do I simply need to remove the click function for larger screens as I can do the rest with CSS. How could I remove the function then put it back on window resize?

Answer (score 2):

couldn't you combine it and write

```
$('#access').on('click mouseenter', 'li.dd a', function() {
```

or are there any sideeffects if you do that?

*Edit:* hover is wrong... you have to use mouseenter

Comment: but that would process the function on both ?!?!

Comment: @ManseUK it does, but I was just testing to see if that mattered.